# How do I get the max value from the sum of two columns in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Given two columns, A and B like so:

```
   | A  | B
-------------
1  | 6  | 2
2  | 4  | 5
3  | 8  | 2
```

Can I write an excel formula that will achieve `=MAX(A1+B1,A2+B2,A3+B3)` without having to type every row into the formula?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it with an "array formula" like this

`=MAX(A1:A3+B1:B3)`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

You can add an INDEX function to make it a "regular" formula, i.e.

`=MAX(INDEX(A1:A3+B1:B3,0))`

or a non-array version for Excel 2010 or later versions

`=AGGREGATE(14,6,A1:A3+B1:B3,1)`

`14` indicates `LARGE` in `AGGREGATE` function - with the 1 at the end meaning the largest

Comment: Just curious, why does this require `ctrl`-`shift`-`enter`? It seems like a normal formula.

Comment: As a "rule of thumb", any "calculated array" - in this case the array calculated by adding two ranges - results in a formula that requires CSE, although some functions (like SUMPRODUCT and LOOKUP) don't normally need CSE even with calculated arrays - to allow normal entry you can add an INDEX function - I edited my answer to the effect

Answer (score 3):

Use the Array Formula:

**=MAX((A1:A100)+(B1:B100))**

This must be entered with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>ENTER</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key

Answer (score 1):

In visual Basic, writte this :

```
Sub Max_Sum()
Dim col_1, col_2 As Double
Dim Result, Result_Max As Double

Dim nRow As Integer
nRow = 1 'If the started row is the first

Do
    col_1 = Cells(nRow, 1).Value
    col_2 = Cells(nRow, 2).Value
    Result = col_1 + col_2
    If Result > Result_Max Then
        Result_Max = Result
    End If
    nRow = nRow + 1
Loop Until col_1 = "" Or col_2 = ""

'Writte the result in the C3 range
Cells(3, 3).Value = Result_Max
End Sub
```